# Why does default $IFS expand to a newline, when "for word in $string" splits on spaces?

Tags: bash, echo, ifs

When I execute the code below via command line:

```
(
    mystring="foo:bar baz rab"
    for word in $mystring; do
      echo "Word: $word"
    done
)
```

The result I get is:

```
Word: foo:bar
Word: baz
Word: rab
```

This means that the `$IFS` would be interpreted as a space character. 
But then I try to reverse it by doing the following:

```
echo "foo:bar${IFS}baz${IFS}rab"
```

And prints:

```
foo:bar
baz
rab
```

Which now means the `$IFS` is a `\n`. I would have expected `"foo:bar baz rab"`

What is causing this inconsistency?

Comment: `IFS` by default behaves equivalent to `IFS=$' \t\n'`; it contains **three** characters.

Comment: I see, so, a word boundary is any of those characters?

Comment: Correct, any character in IFS will act as a word boundary.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to do `for word in $mystring`, consider disabling globbing first -- or using `read -r -a myarray <<<"$mystring"; for word in "${myarray[@]}"` -- to prevent a word of `*.txt` from being replaced with a sequence of files matching that sequence as a glob (or causing an error if `failglob` is set, or disappearing silently if `nullglob` is set).

Comment: Pipe your `echo` statement through something like `hexdump -C`, and you'll see that a space and a tab precede each newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IFS` contains **three** characters by default: Space (first), tab (second), newline (third).

This means any one of these three characters can act as a word separator. `$*` uses only the first of those three to separate words.

If you want to generate a string from an array, separated by the first character in IFS, consider:

```
# Combine array elements with the first character in IFS using ${array[*]}
array=( foo:bar baz rab )
echo "${array[*]}"
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused why it's not "${array[$*]}" which only echos the first element. I can't find the pattern here :(

Comment: `${array[$*]}` is trying to convert the string created by expanding your script's argument list with spaces between the items (`$*`) into a numeric index. There's no variable by whatever name that turns into (if there *are* no arguments in your current context, it's just an empty string), so it converts to `0`. If the result of `$*` were neither numeric *nor* a valid variable name (which could be dereferenced to try to find a numeric variable or a name thereof), nor an empty string, it would be an error.

Comment: `$*` behaves like `${array[*]}` (but operating on the shell's argument list); `"$@"` behaves like `"${array[@]}"` (but operating on the shell's argument list). Does that help, in terms of finding a pattern?

Comment: makes perfect sense now thanks, a little difficult coming from java. Keep thinking the [*] is taken literally as index using that character

Comment: Only associative arrays (bash equivalent to Java's `Map<String,String>`) can have non-numeric indexes, so it *is* possible to have an asterisk or an `@` as a literal array index, but only if your array was created with `declare -A` or an equivalent -- in that case, it's quoting that makes the difference: after `declare -A arr=( ['*']='hello' ['@']='world' )`, you get two different results from `echo "${arr[*]}"` and `echo "${arr['*']}"`

Comment: ...on which point, even bash's numeric "arrays" are sparse -- they're not implemented as arrays in memory, but are much more like a `Map<Integer,String>` equivalent.

Comment: you just saved me at least an hour of fumbling through documentation thanks!